# Disappearing negative signs when evaluating a sinh^-1 integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

$$\int_{-2}^{6} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(-x)^2}} \, dx$$

When performing this integral on paper, I get

$$\sinh^{-1}(6) - \sinh^{-1}(-2) $$

But when I type it on wolframalpha, I get the unintuitive answer

$$\sinh^{-1}(6) + \sinh^{-1}(2) \approx 3.935$$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%281%2Fsqrt%281%2B%28-x%29%5E2%29%29+from+-2+to+6

What's happening to the negative signs?

Comment: $\sinh$ is an odd function, so $\sinh (-x) = -\sinh x$, and in this particular case, $-\sinh(-2) = +\sinh(+2)$.

Comment: Thank you. I have to look more closely next time.

Comment: Me too ;) It's $\sinh^{-1}$. But of course that is odd too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sinh^{-2} x$ is an odd function:
$$\sinh^{-1}(x):=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\\
\implies \sinh^{-1}(-x)=\ln(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1})=\ln(-(x-\sqrt{x^2+1}))=\ln\left(\dfrac{x-\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x^2-1-x^2}\right)=\\
\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{x-\sqrt{1+x^2}}\dfrac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{x-\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=-\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\\
\implies \sinh^{-1}(-x)=-\sinh^{-1}(x)\\
\text{Thus, } -\sinh^{-1}(-2)=-(-\sinh^{-1}(2))=\sinh^{-1}(2)$$